# how to save modified_by & modified_date with @SQLDelete?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sql-delete

I'm working on a project with Spring boot & Hibernate. all this time I'm using soft delete with
`@SQLDelete` annotation. E.g i have my entity like this:

User.java:

```
@Entity
@Data
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE user SET deleted = 0 WHERE user_id = ?")
@Where(clause="deleted = 0")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    private String email;

    private String password;
}
```

BaseEntity.java:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date createdDate;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedBy
    protected String createdBy;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date modifiedDate;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedBy
    protected String modifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT DEFAULT 0")
    protected Long deleted;
}
```

but there's something I just realize that every time a user deletes a record the deleted field is updated, but the modifiedBy and modifiedDate not updated. is there any other way I can fix this?

thanks for your help

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Susan Mustafa for the answer. I've tried with `@PreRemove` but still the modifiedBy and modifiedDate are not updated. Here's the change that I've made:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date createdDate;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedBy
    protected String createdBy;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date modifiedDate;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedBy
    protected String modifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT DEFAULT 0")
    protected Long deleted;

    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove() {
        this.modifiedBy = UserSession.getUsername();
        this.modifiedDate = new Date();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's how I deleted the record.

UserRepository.java:

```
public UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

}
```

UserService.java

```
public interface UserService {
    /// other method
    void deleteUser(Long userId);
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    /// other method
    void deleteUser(Long userId) {
       userRepository.deleteById(userId);
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity deleteUser(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Deleted Successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: You know what could help, is to show us how you are doing Delete exactly...

Comment: I've updated my question @Susan Mustafa